# Cannot install Perl module due to missing cc1 compiler on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: perl, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to install `Moose` using `cpanm` on Ubuntu 14.04, but I get an error saying:

```
Running Makefile.PL
Configuring Moose-2.1210 ... cc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
This distribution requires a working compiler at Makefile.PL line 52.
N/A
! Configure failed for Moose-2.1210. See /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1407056127.30229/build.log for details.
```

I have installed `gcc` compiler version 4.8.2. :

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-i386 --with-arch-directory=i386 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-targets=all --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=i686-linux-gnu --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=i686-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

Here is more output (the whole output is available [here](http://pastebin.com/cwu5vnEw)):

```
$ cpanm -v Moose 
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7004 on perl 5.018002 built for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
Work directory is /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1407056507.30283
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.05
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.31 ... Yes (6.66)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::Install 1.46 ... Yes (1.59)
Searching Moose on cpanmetadb ...
Unpacking Moose-2.1210.tar.gz
--> Working on Moose
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Moose-2.1210.tar.gz ... OK
Moose-2.1210/
Moose-2.1210/author/
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/
Moose-2.1210/bin/
Moose-2.1210/Changes
Moose-2.1210/Changes.Class-MOP
Moose-2.1210/dist.ini
Moose-2.1210/doc/
Moose-2.1210/inc/
Moose-2.1210/lib/
Moose-2.1210/LICENSE
Moose-2.1210/Makefile.PL
Moose-2.1210/MANIFEST
Moose-2.1210/META.json
Moose-2.1210/META.yml
Moose-2.1210/mop.c
Moose-2.1210/mop.h
...
<cut>
...
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/run_yml.pl
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/Bench/
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/Plain/
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/Plain/Point.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/Plain/Point3D.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/Immutable/
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/Installed/
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/Point.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/Point3D.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/Installed/Point.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/Installed/Point3D.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/Immutable/Point.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/MOP/Immutable/Point3D.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/Bench/Accessor.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/Bench/Construct.pm
Moose-2.1210/benchmarks/cmop/lib/Bench/Run.pm
Moose-2.1210/author/docGenerator.pl
Moose-2.1210/author/extract-inline-tests
Moose-2.1210/author/find-dupe-test-numbers
Entering Moose-2.1210
Checking configure dependencies from META.json
Checking if you have Dist::CheckConflicts 0.02 ... Yes (0.11)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.30 ... Yes (6.66)
Checking if you have File::Spec 0 ... Yes (3.40)
Checking if you have ExtUtils::CBuilder 0.27 ... Yes (0.280210)
Running Makefile.PL
Configuring Moose-2.1210 ... cc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
This distribution requires a working compiler at Makefile.PL line 52.
! Configure failed for Moose-2.1210. See /home/hakon/.cpanm/work/1407056507.30283/build.log for details.
N/A
```

Comment: Install "a working compiler"?

Comment: I have installed gcc version 4.8.2. What more do I need? See updated question for more information..

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=cc1&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any

Comment: The module installer tries to run cc, not gcc. Does cc work for you when invoked from the command line?

Comment: Thanks @n.m. I found the problem. There was a conflict between a `cc` command in my home folder and the compiler in `/usr/bin/cc`. In my `~/.bashrc` I had added `$HOME/bin` before `/usr/bin` on the `$PATH`, so it did not find the correct command..